# Remove all special characters even 'éèô' from string

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to remove all special characters contained in a string. I tried some sample script but it doesn't remove all special characters.

`echo "SamPlE_@tExT%, reééééally ?" | sed -e 's/[^a-z^A-Z]//g'`

**Output** : `tExTreééééaôlly`

**Expected** : `tExTreally`

Comment: Why is `SamPlEtEx` not in output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest would be to run the command with the `C` locale:

```
echo "SamPlE_@tExT%, reééééally ?" | LANG=C sed 's/[^a-zA-Z]//g'
```

Output:

```
SamPlEtExTreally
```